# Target ID to hide active link with pseudo ID?

Tags: jquery

I have a unique situation where a dynamically driven link contains a type of ID I'm not able to target and hide with jquery. I'm calling it a pseudo ID, since it reminds me of pseudo classes, but I don't even think this type of ID exists.

Do you have a solution how I can target this link and hide it with this ID? I'm not able to physically change the ID, so I'm stuck hoping there was a way to get at it with jquery.

Here is the HTML with the ID in question:

```
<a href="http://www.helloworld.com" id="msgForum:print">test</a>
```

I tried removing it with an easy hide function, but I'm not able to target it, because of the `:print` that is present.

```
$('#msgForum:print').hide();
```

Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YAMVA/1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `\\` to escape any special characters.

```
$('#msgForum\\:print').hide();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YAMVA/3/

**Specials characters** : 
`!"#$%&'()*+,./:;?@[\]^{|}~`

Comment: thank you for this lesson! and for the quick response! i wish I could give the feedback to everyone!

Answer (score 4):

You just need to escape the special character `:` in the selector with double backslashes.

```
$('#msgForum\\:print').hide();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jqHES/

from the [jQuery Selectors documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

```
To use any of the meta-characters ( such as  !"#$%&'()*+,./:;?@[\]^`{|}~ ) as a literal part of
a name, it must be escaped with with two backslashes: \\. For example, an element with id="foo.bar", 
can use the selector $("#foo\\.bar").
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take advantage of id attribute selector:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/YAMVA/2/)

```
$('[id="msgForum:print"]').hide();
```